# Ajax multiple parameters through url

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

The double parameter url passing isn't working as the error alert is popping up
Getting the alert error:

> Syntax Error: Unexpected string

I'm getting a new error in firefox.

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

```
function GetSlotTime() {

        var SlotDate = document.getElementById('field3-datepicker').value;

        var SlotType = document.getElementById('field6').value;

        alert(SlotDate);
        alert(SlotType);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:"@Href("~")AjaxMethods/GetSlotTime.cshtml?SlotDate="+SlotDate+"&SlotType="+SlotType,

            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                des = data;
                $("#field4").append(des);

            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textstatus, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: `contentType: "application/json",` makes no sense at all. You are making a GET request, there is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: When I run that code, I get an unexpected token because you've put a `~` operator between two strings here: `url:"@Href("~")AjaxMet`. I can't reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Reload the page. Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "load_page.php",
data: 'slotdate='+slotdate+'&slottype='+slottype,
dataType: "html",
success: function(msg){     
if(msg!=0)
{
$('#pageContent').html(msg);
}
}
});
```

Then in PHP (for example) just do:

```
$slottype = $_GET['slottype'];
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what are you trying to do, but you can send params with "data":

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

so you can use

```
data: { SlotDate: SlotDate, SlotType: SlotType }
```

Comment: Why did you change it to `type: "POST"`?

Comment: I didn't, i pasted the jquery example for $.ajax, straight from jquery documentation page, then i added the specific data field for him below